# generating array of object without keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like so:

```
[
 0:'some value'
 1:'some value'
 3:'some value'
]
```

and what i want is a nice array of objects without keys for an editabale select like so:

```
       [
          {value: 1, text: 'Active'},
          {value: 2, text: 'Blocked'},
          {value: 3, text: 'Deleted'}
       ]
```

i have tried looping and assigning, but i am getting the same result.
how can i achieve this array:

```
cities.push({value:value, text:value});
```

Comment: Your "array of objects" isn't valid syntax.  What exactly do you have to begin with?  What do you mean by "without keys"?  Arrays and objects *always* have keys/indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial 'array of objects' doesn't make sense...do you mean those are the properties of a given single object?

If so, what you need to do is use a for in loop to loop over the objects properties, e.g.

```
for (var property in obj) {
  cities.push({value: property, text: obj[property]});
}
```

Comment: Be careful with `for .. in`.  If you are using it to loop over an array, then you are gonna get all the other properties of the array too, like `length`.  Use a "normal" for loop (or `arr.forEach()`) for looping over an array.

Comment: From my understanding of his question, he does not have an array, but an object which happens to be in an array-like structure. That may be wrong...as we both previously mentioned his 'array of objects' is unclear.

Comment: I agree with your thought, I just wanted to warn about `for .. in` on arrays vs on objects.